# Were Shakuntala and Rama contemporaries?

Tags: rama, dwapara-yuga, treta-yuga, vishvamitra, shakuntala

I have this chronology in mind:

1. Vishvamitra meets Menaka.
2. Vishvamitra and Menaka give birth to Shakuntala.
3. Vishvamitra and Menaka separate.
4. Vishvamitra gives Shakuntala to Rishi Kanva and carries on with his quest to become Brahmarshi.
5. Vishvamitra mentors Rama.
6. Rama defeats Ravana.
7. Shankutala gives birth to Bharat.
8. Bharat is ancestor of Kurus and later Mahabharata happens.

The story of Shakuntala leading upto Bharat and Kurus plays out in Dwapar Yug while the story of Rama is in Treta Yug. Treta came before Dwapar. Shakuntala seems to be a contemporary of Rama based on the events mentioned above.

How come Treta and Dwapar Yugs seem to be happening at the same time? What is the mistake here?

Comment: Where is it said that Bharata Dauṣyanti was born in Dvāparayuga? On what basis have you assumed the janma of Śakuntalā's son to be later than Rāvaṇa's death?

Comment: It's certan that Bharata Dauṣyanti was born before Rāma Dāśarathi, for the kathā of Viśvāmitra-Menakā was already a past in the life of Rāma. If Bharata Dauṣyanti was really born in Dvāparayuga, then it is not the 24th Dvāparayuga actually which is being referred to. Rāma was born in the 24th Tretāyuga, so Bharata would be born in <24th Dvāparayuga. According to me, Bharata was either born in the same yuga as Rāma (but before him), or in a prev. yuga (of the same mahāyuga or prev. mahāyuga).

Comment: I am assuming you are aware of the basic timeline. 1 manvantara contains 71/72 mahāyugas. And each of the mahāyugas contain the four yugas (Satya, Tretā, Dvāpara, and Kali). The current mahāyuga is the 28th, while Rāma was born in the 24th mahāyuga. There have been 28 Dvāparayugas in this manvantara, before our 28th Kaliyuga, and there are many more to come.

Comment: What is the link between Bharat and Kurus? How many generations passed between them? That can help answer some of it?